# ArrayList of ArrayLists for pegs and discs in towers of hanoi game

Tags: java, arraylist, towers-of-hanoi

I am building a towers of hanoi game that can be played from the console or the command line.  Note this isn't a recursive program; I am trying to build a GAME that can be played by the user.  I am using an ArrayList of ArrayLists to store the pegs(1,2,3) and the discs(N) chosen by the user.

My instance variables and constructor:

```
private ArrayList lists;
private ArrayList peg1 = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList peg2 = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList peg3 = new ArrayList<>();

//Constructor
public TowersOfHanoi() {

   ArrayList<Integer>[] lists = new ArrayList[3];
   lists[0]= this.peg1;
   lists[1]= this.peg2;
   lists[2]= this.peg3;

}
```

How I initialize the game

```
public ArrayList initializeGame(int n) {

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        peg1.add(i);
        }
}
```

I am trying to make a move method that will take two INTS as parameters for the from and to posts.  I.E. user moves disc from post N to post N, and checks if that move is legal.

I have tried to figure this out for the last couple hours but I can't even figure out how to get the appropriate peg and move the disk from one peg to another let alone check to see that a larger disk isn't being moved on top of a smaller disk.  This is the method I came up with and I am getting a null pointer exception which makes me think that `lists` is not initialized correctly.  This is the method I have which is obviously wrong.

```
public void move(int moveFrom, int moveTo){

    lists.get(moveTo)
    lists.add(0, moveTo);
}
```

So can anyone help me understand how to use an int as an index to get the appropriate peg (int is entered by user) and move a disc?

Comment: Your `lists` array is shadowing the `lists` field (which is an ArrayList, not an array, by the way).  Thus the field is never assigned and gets `null` as a default value.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying I changed to `this.lists = new ArrayList[3]`.  But, my move method is still all wrong and just not sure how to approach the logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lists is not being initialized because you declare an instance object of type `ArrayList`

```
private ArrayList lists;
```

Which is null.  Then, in your constructor, you declare and initialize a local object of type `ArrayList[]` - as in an array of ArrayLists

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] lists = new ArrayList[3];
```

You then put your pegs into this array of `ArrayList`'s

```
lists[0]= this.peg1;
lists[1]= this.peg2;
lists[2]= this.peg3;
```

and then you exit the constructor without doing anything with the array.  You need to either:

```
private ArrayList[] lists;
private ArrayList peg1 = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList peg2 = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList peg3 = new ArrayList<>();

//Constructor
public TowersOfHanoi() {

   lists = new ArrayList[3];
   lists[0]= this.peg1;
   lists[1]= this.peg2;
   lists[2]= this.peg3;

}
```

OR

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList> lists = new ArrayList<>(3);
private ArrayList peg1 = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList peg2 = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList peg3 = new ArrayList<>();

//Constructor
public TowersOfHanoi() {

   lists.add(this.peg1);
   lists.add(this.peg2);
   lists.add(this.peg3);

}
```

OR most likely

```
private ArrayList[] lists = new ArrayList[3];
private ArrayList peg1 = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList peg2 = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList peg3 = new ArrayList<>();

//Constructor
public TowersOfHanoi() {

   lists[0]= this.peg1;
   lists[1]= this.peg2;
   lists[2]= this.peg3;

}
```

Comment: Ok I realize the mistake I made in the constructor.  However, when I fix it I can't use `lists.get` or `lists.add`  Your first and third constructors will work, but, I get errors with the second one.  My biggest problem is understanding the logic in the move method.  I don't know how I can get an INT from a user and use that to access the appropriate peg.  I assume I can do something like `lists[moveFrom].get(0);` but I'm really not sure how to say it..

Comment: Sorry, my first two examples both had syntax errors, but I fixed them.  If we assume you go with #3, which is my suggestion, then you would access a peg using `lists[moveFrom].get(peg_number)`  you could check the size of a stack with `list[moveFrom].size`

Comment: Thank you I ended up using a syntax very similar to number 2.  Thanks for fixing.